# Ways to store dynamic data produced by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I am learning web development. I have come across a part in jquery where i can dynamically produce html elements like div table etc. But i wanted to know how to store these dynamically produced data. What are all the ways to store these jquery dynamic data?? And if i want to store it in mysql how to do?? It will be helpful if you have any reference links or code. Pls help me with this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you know any server side programming languages?

Comment: You can use HTML5 localstorage or cookies to store data !

Comment: i know java for server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic data often comes from a JSON string. JSON represents an object (or a set of objects) that can be used directly in Javascript.

Using Jquery, you can get JSON with this utility method : `getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )`

So you have to provide an URL responding with JSON, to be used as the `url` parameter in `getJSON` function.

It can be either a static file (ie `http://domain:port/data/myData.json`) or a dynamic content generated by a server side process in the language of your choice (PHP, Java, JS with NodeJS...), ie `http://domain:port/myData.php?filter1=value1`.

Note : JSON is the most standard format for transferring objects to Javascript, but it could any format (CSV, XML, ...)

In the callback method of `getJSON`, you will be provided a plain Javascript object that will contains everything that was in your JSON file, and you could use it to produce whatever you want (`html elements like div table etc`).

If you need to request a SQL backend, you will have to use a server side process to do the SQL request and map it back to a JSON object.